# Configure smtp with smarthost for outgoing e-mails

Tags: magento-1.9, transactional-mail, smtp

I am having an issue sending mails with Magento and a smarthost. Using Magento 1.9 which sends mails through smtp and a queu.

- I configured cron jobs
- Host added the IP to the mailserver
- Installed SMTP Pro Email extension from Aschroder
- The extension does a selftest which responds with a "SMTP server could not open socket"
- I contacted the hosting company and they tell me there probably is a problem in the configuration in the mailsever settings. But I can not set anything more besides the server name and authentication.
- I also checked the mail qeue in the database which is filled. But mails are still not send.

So my main question is, how do we configure the mail settings so mails are send?

Comment: You can use any other SMTP service rather than `smarthost`, I preferred `Mandrill` which is free and easy to configure with SMTP Pro Email extension.

Comment: Thank you that is a good working solution. You made my day becasue i can finally send mails.

But it actually would be great (and it would make sense) to be able to use the server that comes with the hosting.

Comment: Yes, that's true there is setting for sending email through your domain. I added some reference link in answer which might be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Refer below links:

> 1. https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582267
> 2. https://www.murrion.com/2015/01/how-to-send-and-receive-emails-with-mandrill/
> 3. https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582387-How-to-Set-up-Sending-Domains
> 4. https://spinspire.com/article/smtp-relay-mandrill-service

Hope this will help you.